# Склонение фамилии Пятовский

Tags: ономастика, склонение-фамилий

Как склоняется фамилия Пятовский?

Answer (score 5):

Эта фамилия склоняется как прилагательное.

Answer (score 1):

Пятовский - Пятовского - Пятовского - Пятовскому - Пятовским - о Пятовском.